# Pre loading data in database projects

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I have a visual studio database project in my solution for managing changes to database and source control.

I have a script for each table under Scripts/Post-Deployment folder in the project which I run in Script.PostDeployment.sql as follows:

```
:r .\Data.Script1.sql
:r .\Data.Script2.sql
....
```

These script populate required data like lookup tables using "Insert Into tablename..." statements.

The problems I am facing are:

1. If in above example Script1 fails because the database already exists and I am redeploying because of minor change in structure of correcting a spell mistake in data etc., the rest of batch is aborted too.
2. Changes in insert into statements are not propagated because when depolying to existing database first statement in Data.*.sql file will fail since that row already exists.

Is there a way in for visual studio database projects to compare data in existing database and use insert or update based on if a row already exists or not ?

Thanks for your input

Comment: I'd be interested to know if the MSDN article's solution is working for you, does it provide all the control you need?

Comment: I have not got time to explore it further yet. It basically on a backbench right now. But I will update this as soon as I find a viable solutiont or try out Merge. Merge looks promising but syntax dont look too friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MERGE INTO instead of INSERT INTO statements in you Data.*.sql files.

See this MSDN article for details, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problems you've outlined are solved by migration tools like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) and [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/). They record the migrations already applied to a database, so will only run the new changes for a particular release.

Similar tools exist in other languages. I can personally recommend [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), which I've used in command-line mode (for non java projects) and integrated into the application code.